# iPhone 4S - sudden drop in battery percentage

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I have an iPhone 4S and I just ran into a really weird issue the third time now: the battery percentage would suddenly drop 30-40-50%. One minute, it's, say, 69%, the next minute it's 25%. If I put it on a charger, it jumps back to 69% after a few minutes and charges it until 100% and then it works for a while.

It happened again today, I noticed that the camera apps were getting killed even though the battery was at 54%, and then after a minute, the battery would drop to 1% saying low battery. Then it died on me.

I also do not know how to calibrate.

I'm running iOS 8, non-jailbreaked.

Comment: I'm afraid that doing the hard reboot at the end is necessary for the calibration. Try it, and tell us if that solved the issue.

Comment: Try restoring it and check the differences.

Comment: I'd wager this is a hardware issue. Software problems don't tend to manifest in such ways. It's likely a faulty battery.

Comment: I'm curious if the phone will actually die when it reaches 1% or less. So, if you just let the phone go (not charge it), when it jumps to ~25%, does it discharge from 25% percent like you would expect, and then power off?

Comment: My phone is doing the exact same thing. It isn't all the time, but occasionally. One day I went from 57% directly to 18%. Today I went from 37% to 20%. As soon as I put it on the charger it goes back to the percentage it was at before the drop.

Comment: Serious answer now: To fix any battery issues please click : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85156/iphone-4s-sudden-drop-in-battery-percentage

Comment: I'm having the same thing with mine, it's a year old and will only do this when I'm at 8% and jump right down to 1%

Comment: Exactly same issue with a 5S... Will try replacing battery I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up replacing the battery myself. Have no issues with the new battery.

Comment: This sudden drop in capacity is a typical indication that the lithium polymer battery has exceeded it's normal useful life. It could also be a premature failure of the battery, but either way the solution is to get it serviced or replaced in almost all cases.